# How could I read from PHP in another host

Tags: php, xml, curl

I have a proxy in our office which close all the trafic from certain ports. It's a big office so the Security manager won't open any ports. We need some data through the port 9001 which isn't opened.

To bypass this, I put a php script in my server which outputs an XML which needs to be read in my office network. So, I tested at home with a cUrl and worked flawlessly but it seems that now it's grabing nothing.

Tested with var_dump it shows: boolean false with the curl exec

What other methods could I use?

Comment: If (a) the output was perfect on your home system and (b) the open server is providing HTTP, then you should debug the server. CURL should work fine as long as you have it enabled. If not, you can also try using wget inside of an exec.

Comment: It couldn't be a problem of the server because the output from the server is the same whenever you are at home, the office or the beach. It's always an XML no matter where you look at.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could set up a VPN on an allowed port and connect through that. That would probably simplify a lot of other stuff as well. OpenVPN is pretty light and straight-forward to set up.

Answer (score 0):

install a proxy on an external host which is listening on port 80 but fetches from port 9001

Comment: My host already do this. It listen from port 80 since it's a normal hosting and it fetches from 9001 without problems.

Comment: you have an http daemon listen on port 80 and this is fetching from 9001, this is not the same. you asked for other methods.

Comment: Or I'm not understanding you or you aren't understanding me. It's a host where I have a website so it listens from port 80 and since it's able to output the XML grabed from port 9001, my server is able to fetch from 9001. The problem isn't in the server but in my work's network.

Comment: maybe not only your ports are blocked, but certain ips/domains too

Comment: Not this one since I'm able to ping it from the server :-)